# Sentence ending って used for emphasis/explanation or casual quotations?

Tags: particle-って

General Context Regarding Every Sentence: 蛍(mc of show) just moved from Tokyo, to a small town and she doesn't know anyone real well. All of this is from the show のんのんびより.

 
Sentence Context: Parts of the school hallway floor is rotten and one girl(なつみ) jokingly tells 蛍 not to get to close to the damaged areas or else she may fall through.

Then なつみ subsequently says to 蛍:

1. > 冗談冗談。今まで床にはまったお間抜けさんなんていない**って**

To me, this one seems like I could interpret it as either:

- So far, there isn't an idiot that's fallen through the floor... (with emphasis/explanation added)
- **It is said that,** "so far there isn't an idiot that's fallen through the floor."

Previous dialogue leading up to the upcoming sentence in question:
（れんげ）こんなとこに鍵が落ちてるん
（蛍）それ私のだ
（なつみ）鍵なんの
（コマ）何何
（蛍）今日夜まで家に誰もいないから家の鍵持ってきてって

Sentence Context: 蛍 dropped her house key on the ground and someone asks her why she has a key in such a small town.

蛍 tries to explain by saying:

2. > 今日夜まで家に誰もいないから家の鍵持ってきて**って**

This one I honestly have no clue what the って is doing here at all.

My guesses are:

- There won't be anyone at home till' tonight so **I was told**, "bring your key"
- There won't be anyone at home till' tonight so I brought my key. (seems out of place from my understanding though)

Sentence Context: In this scene 蛍 is walking through the small town, with a few other girls. Looking troubled and not saying much, one girl asks her "どうしたの？".

蛍 replies with:

3. > 東京とはずいぶん違うなぁ**って**

With this I'm thinking it could mean either:

- **I was thinking**, (this place) is really different from Tokyo.
- (This place) is really different from Tokyo. (emphasis/explanation added)

Any help regarding the understanding of って used in these sentences would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is the second sentence really 来てって (not 来てて)? If yes, could you add a bit [more context](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2189/5010) for this sentence?

Comment: @naruto Unfortunately no, きてって is taken verbatim from the subtitles. However if you still need to me add more context, I could try to do that for sure.

Comment: You mean the sentence is precisely きてって? Then please add a few previous sentences that led to the sentence in question.

Comment: That's correct. I'll go ahead and add those in for you.

Comment: @naruto I added in all of the sentences that came before the subject in question. However, it's still not much to run off of. My apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 今まで床にはまったお間抜けさんなんていない**って**
> There has been no idiot who got stuck into the floor, **you know**.

This って is originally a quotative marker, but here it's (almost certainly) working like "you know", or "come on". By "with emphasis added", do you mean this effect? The other interpretation ("it is said that") is highly unlikely because she is clearly thinking 床にはまる is like a joke.

> 今日夜まで家に誰もいないから家の鍵持ってきて**って**
> **{I was told / (My parent) told me}** to bring the key (here) since no one will be home until tonight.

This って is a rather simple quotation marker, and everything before って is a quote. Someone (her parent?) told her the part before って. って for emphasis can be used with a request/command, but "*Hey*, bring (now)!" doesn't make sense here.

> 東京とはずいぶん違うなぁ**って**
> **I was thinking** "(oh, this place) is really different from Tokyo".

This って is a simple quotation marker, too. なぁ is an exclamatory sentence-end particle, so this って cannot be a plain emphasis like "come on".

Comment: For your question on the first sentence; going off of your answer to the meaning of って in that sentence, I believe it to be both explanatory and emphatic because it's working somewhat like a よ or ぞ particle. She is also phrasing it in a way that lets us know that she believes it to be to be impossible for someone to be stupid enough to have fallen through and get stuck. Hence the なんて and って. Anyhow I think your answers 100% satisfy my questions. Thank you for the insight you have provided!