# What is the meaning of て in the end of a sentence?

Tags: particles, dialects, anime

This sentence is from Digimon Adventure episode 10.

```
そう都合よくいくわけありまへんて
```

It seems like some kind of 終助詞 but I'm not sure. What is that?

The prior dialogue is:

```
電源さえあれば..
```

He wishes for a source of electricity because they are in some old ruins.

Comment: Related https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/97595/45489

Comment: 促音なくても同じ意味なのですか？？省略でいいですか

Comment: It is in Kansaiben. That's why there's no っ. In Tokyo dialect, it will be そう都合よくいくわけないって.

Comment: Does that mean that people in kansai always tend to not pronounce the っ? Is that a personal preference or a general rule? Do you happen to know? Simples sentence like 何々って意味  would become 何々て意味？

Comment: No. I guess it is mostly because  っ is harder to pronounce after ん. As a second thought ありませんて is possible in Tokyo. But ありませんって is ok too. The latter is a bit emphatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's one (less standard) way to transcribe the particle in speech that's normally written as って. The lack of っ might have to do with ん not ending with a vowel.

It may be seen more often in transcriptions of western dialects, but not exclusively.

From https://www.aozora.gr.jp/cards/000277/files/59445_74041.html

> 何をしゃべったって、腹がへって口がきけませんて顔をしている

The author (辻村伊助) was from Kanto as far as I can see.